# Почему меню не работает на мобильном?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Всем привет. 
У меня есть [такое](https://jsfiddle.net/522ozvkw/) меню. Все работает отлично. Но когда открываю в кроме через [эмулятор телефона](http://i.prntscr.com/uEzi5zj4Roa_U53SjjBPdQ.png), меню перестает работать. В чем может быть проблема?

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var current_index = 0, 
      index, 
      menu, 
      menu_items_count, 
      mouse_down, 
      mouse_start_y, 
      pull_step, 
      total_pull = 80, 
      release = 40,
      pull_release = total_pull + release;

  $(document).on('selectstart', false);

  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#menu li").each(function(i,e){
      $(this).attr("data-index",i) 
    });

    //
    menu = $("#menu").html();
    menu_items_count = $("#menu li").length;
    pull_step = total_pull/(menu_items_count-1);
    //


    $("#menu").css("transform","translate3d("+getItemX(0)+"px,0,0)");
    $("#menu li").removeClass("show");
    $("#menu li").eq(0).addClass("show");
  });

  $(".blog-categories-nav").mousedown(function(e){

    //
    mouse_down = true;
    mouse_start_y = e.pageY;
    //

    if(index == menu_items_count-1) {
      index = 0;
    } else {
      var $item = $("#menu li").eq(index);
      $("#menu").html(menu);
      $("#menu li").eq($item.attr("data-index")).remove();
      $item.prependTo($("#menu"));
      $("#menu li").eq(0).addClass("show");
      $("#menu").addClass("notrans");
      $("#menu").css("transform","translate3d("+getItemX(0)+"px,0,0)");
    }
  });

  $(document).mouseup(function(e){
    if(mouse_down) {
      //
      mouse_down = false;
      $(".blog-categories-nav").animate({height: 46},300);
      $("#menu").removeClass("show");
      $(".pullmenu-icon").removeClass("hide");
      //



      if(index>0) {

        if(index==menu_items_count-1) {

          $(".reload i").addClass("anim");

          setTimeout(function(){
            $("#menu li").removeClass("show");
            $("#menu").css("transform","translate3d("+getItemX(0)+"px,0,0)");
            $(".reload i").removeClass("anim");

            setTimeout(function(){

              $("#menu li").eq(0).addClass("show");
            },500);
          },1000);

        } else {

          current_index = index;

          $(".pages").addClass("hide");

          setTimeout(function(){

            $(".pages").removeClass("hide");
            $(".page").hide();

            switch($("#menu li").eq(index).attr("data-index")) {
              case '0': $("#latest").show(); break;
              case '1': $("#best").show(); break;
              case '2': $("#archive").show(); break;
              case '3': $("#about").show(); break;
                                                             }
          },1000);
        }
      }
    }
  });

  $(document).mousemove(function(e){

    $("#menu").removeClass("notrans");

    if(mouse_down) {

      var diff = Math.max(0, e.pageY - mouse_start_y);
      if(diff>pull_release) diff = pull_release + (diff-pull_release)/(diff*0.01);

      $(".blog-categories-nav").height(46+diff);

      index = Math.max(0,Math.min(menu_items_count-2, Math.floor((diff-release)/pull_step)));
      if(diff>pull_release+pull_step*2) index = menu_items_count-1;

      if(diff>release) {
        $("#menu").addClass("show");
        $(".pullmenu-icon").addClass("hide");
      } else {
        $("#menu").removeClass("show");
        $(".pullmenu-icon").removeClass("hide");
      }

      $("#menu").css("transform","translate3d("+getItemX(index)+"px,0,0)");
      $("#menu li").removeClass("show");
      $("#menu li").eq(index).addClass("show");

      $(".loader-icon").css("transform", "rotate("+(diff*20)+"deg)");
    }
  });

  var getItemX = function(index){
    var $item = $("#menu li").eq(index);
    var item_offset = $item.offset().left;
    var item_width = $item.outerWidth();
    var menu_offset = $("#menu").offset().left;
    var screen_width = $("#screen").width();
    return (menu_offset-item_offset)+(screen_width-item_width)/2;
  };
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 500px;
}

.blog-categories-nav {
  height: 50px;
  background: #384147;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 30;
  padding-left: 60px;
}

#menu {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 3000px;
  position: absolute;
  margin-top: -15px;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-out;
  transition: -webkit-transform .2s ease-out;
  transition: transform .2s ease-out;
  transition: transform .2s ease-out, -webkit-transform .2s ease-out;
}
#menu li {
  color: #FFF;
  display: inline-block;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
  transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
}
#menu li.show {
  opacity: 1 !important;
}
#menu li.reload {
  margin-left: 200px;
  position: relative;
  top: 6px;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0s ease-out;
  transition: opacity 0s ease-out;
}

#menu li a {
  pointer-events: none;
}

#menu li a svg {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 35px;
  height: 35px;
  fill: #fff;
}
#menu.show li {
  opacity: .2;
}
#menu.notrans {
  -webkit-transition: none;
  transition: none;
}

.loader-icon {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 2px solid #fff;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  display: block;
}
.loader-icon.anim {
  -webkit-animation: loader 1s infinite linear;
  animation: loader 1s infinite linear;
}

#loader .loader-icon {
  border: 2px solid #353541;
  border-bottom-color: transparent;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  z-index: 10;
  margin: -8px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes loader {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}

@keyframes loader {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0);
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(359deg);
    transform: rotate(359deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="blog-categories-nav">
  <ul id="menu">
    <li>First</li>
    <li>Second</li>
    <li>Third</li>
    <li class="reload"><i class="loader-icon"></i></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: По правде говоря, ваш пример и по ссылке не работает

Comment: Оно и в сниппете не работает

Comment: Работает же и в сниппетах и так) А проблема у вас в том, что у вас события стоят на `mousedown` , `mouseup`. Вам надо отслеживать действия нажатия на скрин а не мышки. Можете либо сами поискать как написать это, либо есть jquery mobile, там уже готовые ивенты есть по типу `vmousedown`